# Baseline subtraction/removal of a pandas DataFrame (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, baseline

I have some experimental time-lapse data of light emission of cells. Unfortunately, the baseline changes over time (see attached image for example, https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjlBR.png) which makes it harder to analyse the data. For the different samples, the baseline changes in somewhat different ways (for example, some are linearly decreasing/increasing).

I'm wondering if there's some way to remove the baseline of each column in my DataFrame. I've looked into scipy's signal.detrend, but since it's not exactly linear, it doesn't seem useful in this case. I've searched for days before posting this question, but I have yet to find a proper solution. I considered plotting the local minima and subtracting them, but I found that as too blunt of a tool and unwise to implement on a whole DataFrame consisting of 40 columns.

I also found the peakutils baseline module, but I found it unsatisfying. Is there anything I've missed? This should be far from a unique problem within experimental data so I would be very surprised if SciPy doesn't have a proper module. Below is an example of the type of data that I would like to be able to subtract a baseline from, effectively removing the periodicity and making it more or less linear.

```
import numpy as np    
n = 1000
limit_low = 0
limit_high = 0.48
my_data = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, n) \
      + np.abs(np.random.normal(0, 2, n) \
               * np.sin(np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, n)) ) \
      + np.sin(np.linspace(0, 5*np.pi, n))**2 \
      + np.sin(np.linspace(1, 6*np.pi, n))**2
scaling = (limit_high - limit_low) / (max(my_data) - min(my_data))
my_data = my_data * scaling
my_data = my_data + (limit_low - min(my_data))
```

(Code courtesy of user Swier)

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]** (no images / links, just text).

Comment: I apologize. I'm still very new to Python and learning as I go. I didn't really know how to write a short code for a random noisy signal and it wasn't exactly possible to just attach a sample of my DataFrame. However, I managed to find one from an old question and will add it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are dealing with a non-stationary time series. This is a common problem in time series analysis, but there are ways to deal with non-stationary data or make it stationary (such as detrending). These operations are not trivial, and there are various approaches, mostly copied from more stats-oriented languages such as R (eg: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.tsatools.detrend.html).

An LSTM can also deal with non-stationary data. See [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12721/time-series-prediction-using-arima-vs-lstm) for more helpful discussion.

Comment: The problem with the statsmodels module is that I have to specify the order. This becomes problematic when some seem to be second order whereas others seem to be first. I guess I could create two different dataframes according to that and then try the module. But I'm still hoping for a solution that would work on the dataframes directly, as that would simplify it for me since I have 20 different ones (from independent experiments).